# Unable to establish session using service-my-wallet-v3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-14.04, bitcoin, blockchain

I installed `blockchain-wallet-service` and it is works well.

When I try to send Bitcoin I am getting the following Error.

```
1477543337188 - debug: Logging in
undefined
1477543337473 - error: Unable to establish session
```

Please help me to fix this error.